# Retrieving information from another dataframe using .map and lambda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, where-clause

I have two dataframes. `product_list`:

```
    Local Product Code  Country EAN Number      
163 IE492583            Ireland 483759374
171 IE490275            Ireland 103642947
179 IE492648            Ireland 103856384
183 IE498634            Ireland 946294729
189 IE499584            Ireland 649265104
... ... ... ... ... ...
```

and `inventory_helper`:

```
    Product Quantity    Date        Country  Comment    EAN (for IE)
188         1256        2022-09-01  IE       NaN        483759374
189         7032        2022-09-01  IE       NaN        103642947
190         12113       2022-09-01  IE       NaN        103856384
191         1822        2022-09-01  IE       NaN        946294729
192         3094        2022-09-01  IE       NaN        649265104
```

Both dataframes contain the EAN Number. I want to add the corresponding `Local Product Code` from `product_list` to `inventory_helper`. Keep in mind that the dataframe `product_list` contains data for multiple countries, and therefore might contain multiple rows with the same EAN Number, but for different countries (and therefore different Local Product Codes).
I tried using:

```
inventory_helper['Product'] = np.where(inventory_helper['Country'] != 'IE',\
                                      (inventory_helper['Country'] + inventory_helper['Product']),\
                                       inventory_helper['EAN (for IE)'].map(lambda x: product_list[(product_list['Country'] == 'Ireland') & (product_list['EAN Number'] == x)]['Local Product Code'])
)
```

However, my output in the `Product` column contains a series instead of only the product code:

```
    Product                                        Quantity Date        Country Comment EAN (for IE)
188 217 IE492583 Name: Local Product Code, dty...   1256    2022-09-01  IE      NaN     483759374
189 497 IE490275 Name: Local Product Code, dty...   7032    2022-09-01  IE      NaN     103642947
190 498 IE492648 Name: Local Product Code, dty...   12113   2022-09-01  IE      NaN     103856384
191 511 IE498634 Name: Local Product Code, dty...   1822    2022-09-01  IE      NaN     946294729
192 370 IE499584 Name: Local Product Code, dty...   3094    2022-09-01  IE      NaN     649265104
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a {Country to 2_letter_code} like the one mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) to map your 'Country' column in `product_list` dataframe and then do a merge based on `['Country', 'EAN Number']`

Lets say the Country-2_letter_code dict is `country_codes` then the solution is:

```
inventory_helper.merge(product_list.assign(Country_Code=product_list['Country'
                       ].map(country_codes)), left_on=['Country', 'EAN'
                       ], right_on=['Country_Code', 'EAN Number'],
                       how='left')
```